# Converting virtual directory to application on IIS

Tags: iis

i have worked for a year now , on server side applications and everytime i add a site to the iis it is added as a virtual directory. none of my web sites worked as a virtual directory on the iis. all applications always had bugs untill the minute i converted them to applications. 
after converting the main folder to application everything works.
what does it mean to "convert to application" and why all problems are solved when i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the guidance provided by the IIS team http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis/?