# Redirect user to login if not logged in ASP.NET web form using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, authentication, webforms

I'm trying to develop  web app in ASP.NET web forms using C# and I've looked everywhere I could on the internet, but I found no solution to the problem. I've tried editing the default Web app template, to restrict a user from accessing any page if the user is not logged in. The default page should be the log in page and if the user clicks on anything else, he/she must be redirected to login page. Using MVC is easier, with just one bit of code on web.config but I've no idea what to do here in the web form

This is currently what my web.config contains.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Where exactly I need to change?

Comment: You haven't really specified your problem, but from what I make of it, there's two things. You need to set the config <deny users="?"/> to general config, not just any page. Second is that you might need to define login path in the config file.

Comment: I simply want to create a member role based web application, where a user requires to log in before the user is allowed to view the contents in the website. If the person is not registered, the system won't allow to view the contents and will redirect the user to login first. Please note that the user is not allowed to register by himself and he needs to contact the administrator to register.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 2):

The shortest path to what you want is to use [forms authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) with a [login  URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl(v=vs.110).aspx), where you'd add something like this to your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">   
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

The forms authentication mechanism will issue a cookie to a user when they log in.  If they attempt to access a page without the cookie, or with a cookie that has expired, the site will detect this via the [FormsAuthenticationModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule(v=vs.110).aspx), which inspects each and every request that hits the site.  If the user isn't authenticated, it'll automatically issue a redirect to the `loginUrl` that you have specified (login.aspx in my example).

You can use a similar approach if you are using other authentication methods. In pretty much all cases there will be some mechanism that looks for a cookie indicating that the user has signed on.

Comment: I'm sorry, just a little puzzled, where do I paste that code? do I remove the original code in web.config, which is there by default since I started the application?

Comment: Follow the first link.

Comment: I get the following error:

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

<authentication mode="Forms">

Comment: Sounds like you need to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113492/converting-virtual-directory-to-application-on-iis).

Answer (score 0):

Mmm....okay lets do it by another way,
First on the login page, in code behind (The C# code not the HTML)
you must create a session like this

```
Session["user"] = username;
```

you must create the Session before redirect the user to any page on your website
, Now you created the session with the username or the email whatever you like to store in the session, You must check for the session in every page on your website in the Page_Load method in code behind 
to check for the session you do it like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["user"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true); 
        }
```

where the "login.aspx" is the page in your website that the user will redirected to so, Now if `Session["user"]` is null the server will go to login.aspx with "just one bit of code"
and to clear the session on the logout button you do it like

```
                Session.Clear();
                Session.Abandon();
                Session.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: Do I need to paste your code in all the pages? I mean, shouldn't I make any changes to web.config then?